# Sharing a text file (csv) with share_plus: "unable to attach file"

Tags: flutter, share-plus

I want to get data from Firestore, convert it into csv format, then share it using the user's method of choice (e.g. email). I'm using the [csv package](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) to convert the data to csv, the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to get the directory to write the file to the phone, and the [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package to share the file.

However, when I tap a share method (e.g. Gmail, Outlook, Whatsapp), it opens the right app but then I get a message on the phone like "Unable to attach file" (but there is no error in my app). The file is definitely being written as I can read it and it comes back with the expected string. The `ShareResultStatus` that is returned by the share is 'successful' Can anyone figure it out what the problem is and how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
Future exportData() async {
    // Dummy data (in reality, this will come from Firestore)
    List<List> dummyData = [
      ['Date', 'Piece', 'Rating'],
      [DateTime.utc(2022, 05, 01), 'Sonata', 4],
      [DateTime.utc(2022, 05, 02), 'Sonata', 2],
    ];

    // Turn into CSV
    String csvData = _convertToCsv(dummyData);

    // Write to local disk
    await _writeData(csvData);

    // Share
    String filePath = await _filePath;
    final result =
        await Share.shareFilesWithResult([filePath], mimeTypes: ['text/csv']);
    print(result.status);
  }
```

And here are the functions used in above code:

```
 Future<String> get _filePath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return '${directory.path}/my_practice_diary_data.csv';
  }

  Future<File> _writeData(String csvData) async {
    String filePath = await _filePath;
    final file = File(filePath);
    return file.writeAsString(csvData);
  }

  String _convertToCsv(List<List> data) {
    String result = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(data);
    return result;
  }
```

Note: I've tried doing it both as txt and csv files, got same result

*** EDIT (06/06/2022): After a lot of reading and watching youtube videos, I have come to realise that the problem is that the directory `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` is only accessible by my app (and hence the app that is is being shared to, like gmail, cannot read it).

For now I have worked around it by using the package [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) and using user's google credentials to send emails (I followed these helpful youtube tutorials: [Flutter Tutorial - How To Send Email In Background [2021] Without Backend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDwst9icjAY) and [Flutter Tutorial - Google SignIn [2021] With Firebase Auth - Android, iOS, Flutter Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1k-gITZA9CI).

However, it would still be nice to know a nice way to generate a file and share it using share_plus, as per my original question. I believe that this can be achieved via one of two ways:

1. Find a way to allow other apps to access this specific file in the app directory; or
2. Find a way to download the file into an external storage (like downloads folder), then share that. (I cannot find a way to do this on both Android and iOS).

Anyone who knows how to do these or any other solution to the problem, please share!

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? Thanks

Comment: @beria no I haven't unfortunately - in my app, only users who sign up with a Google account can export data even though I would like this function to available to all users :-(

Comment: I have almost the exact same scenario but AWS instead of Firebase. I can only answer half of your question, Path provider now has a function called  getExternalStorageDirectory() but it only exists on Android. I am curious if you can quickly try this and see if you can share on whatsapp!

Answer (score 0):

I was just attempting something similar and this is how I was able to share a csv file with the share_plus

```
 // Convert the data to CSV format
                    String csvContent =
                        const ListToCsvConverter().convert(csvData);
                    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                    final csvFilePath =
                        await File('${directory.path}/gear.csv').create();
                    await csvFilePath.writeAsString(csvContent);
                    final files = <XFile>[];
                    files.add(XFile('${directory.path}/exportData.csv',
                        name: 'Gear Back Up'));

                    /// Share Plugin
                    Share.shareXFiles(files,
                        text: 'My Exported Data!');
```